# How can re-create the db file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I create an app by rails new I skip the few options which I never used.

> rails new backend --api --skip-action-mailer --skip-action-mailbox --skip-active-storage --skip-action-cable --skip-javascript --skip-test --database=postgresql

...but I realized I can not find my .db file. Is this because I skip the test or action-storage? I suddenly think I should not use --skip options if it is not clear idea...

Comment: Please make the question more clear. Who cannot find the db file, you or the program? What is the meaning of "I suddenly think I should not use --skip options if it is not clear idea"?

Answer (score 1):

Based on you question it sounds like you have not run **rails db:create** at the command line yet. You must do this once your Rails project has been created in order to access the database.

Comment: Thank you for looking into my problem. I did ```rails db:create``` but the database isn’t a file with a .db

Comment: Postgres doesn't store its database in the location like SLQLite inside the rails project. It is a Database Server that stores its databases in its own location. You just connect to it. Here is a link to a good tutorial on working with PostgreSQL:

<https://robrace.dev/setting-up-rails-and-postgresql/>

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres stores data in own folder, only sqlite stores data in your project folder.
For database configuration check [config/database.yml](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information.
I didn't know PostgreSQL, the database isn’t a file with a .db extension, it’s a database server running locally ok but
If you know any extension for this problem solve please advise me